# Python desired capabilities error

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium

After setting the desired capabilities (`desired_caps`), I am getting an error with my script. The error is

> `if desired_capabilities is None:`
>   ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

Here is the code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from appium import webdriver
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import desired_caps
from webdriver import WebDriver as Remote
class CNNEndToEnd(unittest.TestCase):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0.1'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Samsung'
    #desired_caps['app'] = PATH('../../../apps/selendroid-test-app.apk')
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.vending'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.AssetBrowserActivity'
    print desired_caps
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)


    def testACNNInstallAndLaunch(self): 
        print "**************************"
        print "********APP INSTALL*******"
        print "**************************"
        print "here---------"
        #appid = "com.cnn.mobile.android.phone"
        if (self.driver.is_app_installed("com.cnn.mobile.android.phone")):
            print "-----App ALready Installed"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(CNNEndToEnd)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manusimply/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.8.0.201706061859/pysrc/_pydev_runfiles/pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "/Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/CNN_PoC/CNN_New.py", line 2, in <module>
    from appium import webdriver
  File "/Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/Appium-Python-Client-0.2/appium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from webdriver import WebDriver as Remote
  File "/Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/Appium-Python-Client-0.2/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 15, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/selenium-3.4.3/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/selenium-3.4.3/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/selenium-3.4.3/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 79
    if desired_capabilities is None:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
ERROR: Module: CNN_New could not be imported (file: /Users/manusimply/Desktop/Eclipse/CNN_PoC/CNN_New.py).
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, as i am new to this community i dont have proper idea about asking the Queries..

From above code i'm not able to  run my script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this should get you going on guidelines of asking.

Comment: Please explain what you expect to see, what you see instead, and what you've done to attempt to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I m getting below issue while running above code

Comment: After setting desired capabilities i am getting error..
 if desired_capabilities is None:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DesiredCapabilities object, not just a list of capabilities that you want to implement. It will make life a bit easier for you. Initialize the variable as shown below, then add you're capabilities into that variable.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
```

See this link for more details on initializing the webdriver in python:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Also make sure that you are using the correct naming conventions for each capability. There is a list of capabilities and their names here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Hopefully that helps out :)

Comment: Thanks, Set the desired capabilities but issue still exists.

Comment: Looking at your stacktrace, you may have not installed selenium correctly. Have you followed the instructions on http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html ?? That site should tell you exactly what to do to get started

Comment: Can you please help me how to create driver object i am trying below bot is showing  
`code`
AttributeError: 'CNNEndToEnd' object has no attribute 'driver'
`code`

self.driver = webdriver.android('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

Answer (score -1):

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0.1'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Samsung'
#desired_caps['app'] = PATH('../../../apps/selendroid-test-app.apk')
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.vending'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.AssetBrowserActivity'
**print(desired_caps)**
```

Also for desired_caps. I would suggest to include udid and use the full appActivity path.